# how to access the value of version number from this json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have parsed a JSON which looks like this, how to access version number and license details from it?

```
'[ { id: 20,
version_number: '1.0',
programming_lang: 'Not available',
primary_contact: 'Not available',
technical_contact: 'Not available',
link: null,
status: 'APPROVED',
description: '<b><font color=#1241cc>Support SPOC: </font></b>Leo RD LIU,  <b><font color=#1241cc>Used by: </font></b>Not Specified',
src_id: 7757,
legal_description: 'Not available',
component_size: 'SMALL',
createdAt: '2016-12-21T00:00:00.000Z',
updatedAt: '2017-03-10T11:47:12.000Z',
component_id: 20,
created_by: 1,
component_licenses: [] } ]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
for(var i in arr){   
    console.log(arr[i].version_number);
}
```

Comment: how can i loop through it if I have multiple things and check each? @Alireza.MH

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse(yourJson)[0].version_number
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert whole json object to javascript object you can use

```
//By using jquery json parser

var obj = $.parseJSON('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(obj['jobtitel']);

//By using javasript json parser
var t = JSON.parse('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(t['jobtitel'])
```

For any specific key value pair you can use:

```
var data = {"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}

var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parsedData.name);
alert(parsedData.skills);
alert(parsedData.jobtitel);
alert(parsedData.res_linkedin);
```